# Make cells negative based upon the value of another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm able to colour cells based upon the value of another with the code below, which I found on this forum

```
Sub ColorMeElmo()
   Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For i = 2 To 100
      Set r1 = Range("D" & i)
      Set r2 = Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
      If r1.Value = "Aankoop" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      If r1.Value = "Verkoop" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbBlue
      If r1.Value = "Dividend" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
   Next i
End Sub
```

Now I'm trying to make cells negative or possitive based upon the value of r1.
I tried this:

```
If r1.Value = "Verkoop" Then r2.Value = r2.Value * (-1)
```

Comment: So test r1 to see if it is negative (or positive like =R1=ABS(R1) then use if()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ibrez’s answer is right. Anyway, I would recommend you write some clearer and more performant code (having 3 conditionals in each loop could be kind of slow if you have a big data sheet).  This is my suggestion:

```
Public Sub ColorMeElmo()
   Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
   Dim color As Long
   Dim value2 As Integer, value3 As Integer

   For i = 2 To 100
      Set r1 = Range("A" & i)
      Set r2 = Range("B" & i)
      Set r3 = Range("C" & i)
      
      Select Case r1
          Case "Aankoop"
              color = vbRed
              value2 = r2
              value3 = r3
          Case "Verkoop"
              color = vbBlue
              value2 = -r2
              value3 = -r3
          Case "Dividend"
              color = vbYellow
              value2 = r2
              value3 = r3
          Case Else
              'some unexpected value would be highlighted in grey
              color = RGB(127, 127, 127)
              value2 = r2
              value3 = r3
      End Select
      
      r2.Interior.color = color
      r2 = value2
      r3.Interior.color = color
      r3 = value3
   Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be that r2 contains multiple cells hence below code will not work

```
If r1.Value = "Verkoop" Then r2.Value = r2.Value * (-1)
```

This needs to be changed to

```
If r1.Value = "Verkoop" Then 
 For Each c In r2.Cells 
     c.Value = c.Value * (-1)
 Next
End if
```